# React GET method doesn't render latest post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, rest

I am using rest-api for my project and when I run the code, GET method works, but everytime I add a post through POST method, data is created in the database but it doesn't render in the app. I have to re-start the app to see latest post.

This is supposed to be live chat app and I am not sure my problem is with the backend or frontend. When I take out all the get and post method it was working fine and it was displaying new message is sent. However when I pull data from the restapi database messages are only rendered when I refresh the page.

main.js

```
class MessagePanel extends Component {

    state={
      messages:[],
      usernames:[]
          }


  componentDidMount(){
    
    axios.get('http://localhost:8888/restapi/messages')
    .then(response =>{
      this.setState({messages: response.data.data[0].messages});
      console.log(response)
    })

                 
  }

 sendMessage=(mes)=>{

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }

  const data={
    username: this.props.username,
    text: mes
  };

    axios.post('http://localhost:8888/restapi/messages', data,{
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(response=> {

    console.log(response)
  })
  
  
 };


 createUsers(){

  this.setState({usernames: 
  [...this.state.usernames, this.props.username]})
  
 }
 
  render()
  
 { 
 
  
  return (
    <div className="MessagePanel">

      <Layout/>
      <SidePanel users={this.state.usernames} />  
      <DisplayMessages messages={this.state.messages} username={this.props.username} />
      <MessageBox sendMessage={this.sendMessage} username={this.props.username}/>

    </div>
  );}
}

export default MessagePanel;
```

DisplayMessage.js

```
class DisplayMessages extends Component {

 //will stop auto scrolling down when you send a message
 componentWillUpdate=()=>{

  const node=ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
  this.shouldScrollToBottom = node.scrollTop +node.clientHeight + 100 >= node.scrollHeight


}

//Auto scrolls when some client messages
componentDidUpdate=()=>{
  if(this.shouldScrollToBottom) {
    const node= ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    node.scrollTop=node.scrollHeight

  }

}

  render(){
return (
  <div className="DisplayMessage">
    <div className='message-container'>
      {this.props.messages.map(message => {
          return(

              <Message  key={message.id} text={message.text} username={message.username} />
              


          )
      })}
   </div>
  </div>
);}
}

export default DisplayMessages;
```

Message.js

```
const message =(props) => {


  let messageClass = 'message-row';


    if (props.isMyMessage) {
        messageClass += ' you-message';
    } else {
        messageClass += ' other-message';
        
    }

    

        return (
    
      <div className='messageClass'>
        <div className='messagedata'>
          
            <div className='userid'>{props.username}</div>
            <div className='textmessage'>{props.text}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
  );
}


export default message;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time you are pulling data from the database is once componentDidMount is called. I would recommend taking a look at the react docs to understand componentDidMount as its an essential part of react https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
Your current react app has no understanding of changes any database changes after the data is first fetched during componentDidMount (essentially when the component first loads).

Depending on how "live" you want the messages to be recieved, you could do something like polling the API for changes every few seconds to check for changes. This would be done by creating a timer that fetches the API every x seconds in componentDidMount, then you can make state changes in componentWillUnmount.

If you want a more "live" solution, it might be worth looking into websockets, however that would require large backend changes.

Comment: thank you for your help. Now it works however this time it is keep sending data through network. Is there anyway I can do it without setting a timer? Like sending a method that everytime I hit the "send" button, it will work?